# jquery-ui draggable on image map causing issues on clickable areas in firefox on android

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I am currently creating an image map which should be draggable and the areas of the image map should open content inside a fancybox. That works fine on desktop and on mobile devices it works in every browser except for firefox.

When I disable the dragging from jquery-ui the areas are clickable again on mobile firefox and working fine.

Here is my simplified code:

```
<div id="image-lageplan-container" style="height:100%;width:100%;height:auto;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
    <img id="image-lageplan" src="/_images/Lageplan_zentralperspektive.png" alt="" usemap="#image-map">
</div>


<map name="image-map">
    <area onclick="return areaclick(this);" shape="poly" title="Test" class="lageplan-area" coords="2776,3907,2775,4003,2834,4023,2898,3999,3000,3969,3022,3985,3024,3924,3029,3920,3000,3886,2946,3808,2823,3838,2781,3889,2761,3904" href="#house-canvas-4" />
</map>

// the container for the image
var $imageLageplanContainer = $("#image-lageplan-container");

$imageLageplanContainer.draggable({
   handle: "img",
   delay: 100,
   start: function () {
      $imageLageplanContainer.css("cursor", "grabbing");
   },
   stop: function () {
      $imageLageplanContainer.css("cursor", "grab");
   }
});

function areaclick(area) {
   var houseCanvasID = $(area).attr("href");
   var houseCanvas = $(houseCanvasID);

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      url: "/ajax.php",
      data: {"m": "getHouseContent", "housecanvas": houseCanvasID},
      success: function (data) {
         $(houseCanvas).html(data);
         $.fancybox.open(houseCanvas);
      }
   });

   return false;
}
```

Anyone have a solution or has experienced similar problems?